# how to get special content-type in http connection with c?

Tags: c, http

Now I can parse all http connection stream by [http-parser](https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser.git). I want get url  where content-type is  `text/html` or `text/xml`.

How to get it? Url is in request, but content-type is always in response header.

I dont known response how to match the request.

I have tied this way, use the url suffix to ensure the url is a html, but failed.

```
const char *strSuffix[] = {
    ".html",
    ".htm",
    ".xml",
    ".jsp",
    ".shtml"
};
for(i = 0;i < ARRAY_SIZE(strSuffix);i++)
    if((tmp = strstr(messages[0].request_url,strSuffix[i])) != NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to check the `REQUEST_METHOD` and the `CONTENT_TYPE` in your environments.

Something like this (not tested):

```
char *request_method = getenv("REQUEST_METHOD") ;
if (strcmp(request_method, "POST") == 0) {
    if (strstr(getenv("CONTENT_TYPE"), "text/xml")) {
        ...
    } else
    if (strstr(getenv("CONTENT_TYPE"), "text/html")) {
        ...
    } ...
```